# Java calling methods on instance variable

Tags: java, coding-style

Got two ways:

> ```
>  String salary = company.getPerson(id).getData().getSalary();      
>  String postcode = company.getPerson(id).getData().getPostCode();
> ```

or

> ```
> Data data = company.getPerson(id).getData();    
> String salary = data.getSalary();     
> String postcode = data.getPostCode();
> ```

Which is the preferred way and why?
Any benefits apart from readability?

Comment: You may find this a relevant read: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter.

Comment: Your first case is less efficient, since you call `getPerson` and `getData` twice rather than once. Furthermore, what if the object changes, and the two lines get different people?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Id actually prefer a third option in case the person does not exist

```
Person person = company.getPerson(id);
if(person != null) {
    Data data = person.getData();
    if(data != null) {
        String salary = data.getSalary();
        String postcode = data.getPostCode();
    }
}
```

It depends whether there may be null values or not.  If you can guarantee there will be no null values then you can eliminate some/all of the null checks.

As another user pointed out in the comment below there may be a case where none of the method calls can return null in which case unless performance is an issue it would really be down to personal preference in my opinion.

I would probably still prefer to seperate them out into seperate calls as I have, even without the null checks.

Comment: You can be true, but it doesn't answer the question. You give a third solution based on an informations you haven't. Who told you `getPerson` can return null? Your post answer more a question like : `which is the safer way?`

Comment: @alain.janinm Well ok, I think mine is both safer and clearer.  I also clearly state below the code that it depends on whether the values are able to be null or not, I have not assumed anything, however, I often find that many people miss this sort of thing and so it is always worth pointing out.

Comment: You're absolutely right about null check. What is missing in your answer is the case where nothing can return null. Then the creation of `data` var has no justification in your answer.

Comment: It depends if performance is much of an issue, if it isn't I'd still prefer this option including the `Data data = person.getData();`.  Just personal preference I guess in the case where none of them can return null.

Comment: Ok, now your answer is more complete ;)

Answer (score 3):

If there is any chance that the intermediate variable may be null, then you should use the second option, together with a null check

```
Data data = company.getPerson(id).getData();    
if (data != null){
    String salary = data.getSalary();     
    String postcode = data.getPostCode();
    // other code here
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It depends on complexity of your getter methods. If, for instance, getPerson(id) method is complex, or/and getData() method is complex, then it may lead to performance problems.

A smart compiler may overcome this issue excluding repeating code parts. But in general, from my point of view, the second way is better.

Answer (score 2):

There is not really a true good style, it depends on the context and on your needs.

Use :

```
 String salary = company.getPerson(id).getData().getSalary();      
 String postcode = company.getPerson(id).getData().getPostCode();
```

If you need to **improve your memory usage**.

Else use :

```
Data data = company.getPerson(id).getData();    
String salary = data.getSalary();     
String postcode = data.getPostCode();
```

If you want to **improve performance**.

For readability it's too subjectives for me. There are both as much readable honestly.

The 2nd example has the advantages of refractoring `company.getPerson(id)` and the variable also allow to perform some verification without having to call `company.getPerson(id)` again. I often prefer this kind of style, but, again, *depending on the needs the first solution can be better if  `getPersonne(id)` and `getData()` can't return null*.

Answer (score 1):

For refactoring / readability and performance reasons I personally find this one the best solution:

```
Data data = company.getPerson(id).getData();    
String salary = data.getSalary();     
String postcode = data.getPostCode();
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to consider performance. While "nice looking code" is great, if there is something expensive to get, keep a reference to it and reuse it.

It is likely that `company.getPerson(id)` involves a database query to retrieve the data, so while the first option looks "neater", the second option is probably better.

But the answer is "it depends" - if each call is cheap, you can use the first option.

Answer (score 1):

One thing to consider is the case where getPerson(...) or getData() might return null.  If any of these ever return null you'll be rewarded with a NullPointerException so the answer might depend on other hidden factors than just readability.

Answer (score 1):

```
 String salary = company.getPerson(id).getData().getSalary();      
 String postcode = company.getPerson(id).getData().getPostCode();
```

This is less readable and scope of data return by `company.getPerson(id).getData()` is at run time only so it will `garbage collected` at that time.

or

```
Data data = company.getPerson(id).getData();    
String salary = data.getSalary();     
String postcode = data.getPostCode();
```

Above is more readable but You are creating one more reference variable of type `Data` so for `garbage collection`  collector will check for reference of 'data' in heap and then if finds it eligible then it will collect.